# $watch a return value of a function

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and I am using angular 1.4.
The issue is:
I am using a simple counter object defined like this:

```
var myCounter = (function(){
                    var count =0;
                    return {
                        "inc": function(){
                            count++;
                        },
                        "dec": function(){
                            if(count>0){
                                count--;
                            }
                        },
                        "getCount": function(){
                            return count;
                        }
                    };
                })();
```

I would like to keep the count variable private and read the value only through 'getCount' function.

Whenever the count increases/decreases I have to perform a set of operations based on the updated value of 'count'. For this I want to use '$watch' to observe the changes. But I can get the value only by invoking the function 'getCount()'.

Please suggest how do I write a '$watch' in this scenario. If this is not a correct approach, please suggest a better one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do `$scope.$watch(myCounter.getCount, function(){})`

Comment: Ok I kind of understand what you are doing there. But why are you not handling it as an object instead of executing it as a anonymous object. Another thing you should consider is what you want to do. You could also attach callbacks to the different functions you have, and then call the specific code for dec, inc or getCount, instead of watching the whole function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/z5k95mwr/

Comment: Thanks Satpal. It worked.

Comment: @KristianBarrett : I wanted to make the count variable private and so I was invoking the outer-most function immediately to create a scope in which inc and dec functions execute. Yes the callback approach is also great. Thank you!

Comment: @user3427320 I mean if you are in the same scope and want to execute some code, I would prefer the callback option, since it doesn't create overhead in form of a watcher. If it is another scope, then you might want to use the watcher approach. You should just be careful with too many watchers, as they can create unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the format for `$watch` is `$watch(watchExpression, listenerFunction)`.  In this case, the watchExpression can be a function to be evaluated.  Therefore, you can pass the `getCount` function (not the result of the function) to the `$watch`.

So,

```
$scope.$watch(myCounter.getCount, function() {})
```

will work, assuming that `myCounter` is accessible to the Controller the `$watch` is defined in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch(myCounter.getCount, function(){
    //Do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute a `callback` whenever `count` is increased/decreased. You can pass `callback` to the constructor, like this:

```
var myCounter = (function(callback){
                    var count =0;
                    return {
                        "inc": function(){
                            callback(++count);
                        },
                        "dec": function(){
                            if(count>0){
                                count--;
                            }
                            callback(count);
                        },
                        "getCount": function(){
                            return count;
                        }
                    };
                })();
```

or you can pass the `callback` on `inc` or `dec` events:

```
var myCounter = (function(){
                    var count =0;
                    return {
                        "inc": function(callback){
                            callback(++count);
                        },
                        "dec": function(){
                            if(count>0){
                                count--;
                            }
                            callback(count);
                        },
                        "getCount": function(){
                            return count;
                        }
                    };
                })();
```

The difference between the two approaches is that in the first one you will do the same in any increasing/decreasing event and in the second one you define the `callback` behavior whenever such an event occurs.

Comment: The callback approach is also great. Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

Nice [article](https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/watch-digest-apply/) on $watch and many more ! I hope this will guide you right way.
In your case you should declare the objects in scope because angular only watches $scope variables,so your code will look like below.

```
$scope.myCounter = (function(){
                var count =0;
                return {
                    "inc": function(){
                        count++;
                    },
                    "dec": function(){
                        if(count>0){
                            count--;
                        }
                    },
                    "getCount": function(){
                        return count;
                    }
                };
            })();

$scope.$watch('myCounter.getCount', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if(newValue != oldValue && newValue !=null){
         //call your function..
       }
})
```